# National identity number for Indians in Schengen visa form

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

What should be mentioned as national identity number for Indians in Schengen tourist visa form?

Answer (score 4):

You can mention your Aadhar number, or leave it blank - you could ask VFS helpdesk. I've done both in separate visa applications (got the visa on both occasions).